# Sum specific row in R - without character & boolean columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame loaded in R and I need to sum one row. The problem is that I've tried to use rowSums() function, but 2 columns are not numeric ones (one is character "Nazwa" and one is boolean "X" at the end of data frame). Is there any option to sum this row without those two columns? So I'd like to start from row 1, column 3 and don't include last column.

My data:

```
structure(list(Kod = c(0L, 200000L, 400000L, 600000L, 800000L, 
1000000L), Nazwa = c("POLSKA", "DOLNOŚLĄSKIE", "KUJAWSKO-POMORSKIE", 
"LUBELSKIE", "LUBUSKIE", "ŁÓDZKIE"), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2006.... = c(9187L, 
481L, 173L, 1072L, 256L, 218L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2007.... = c(11870L, 
652L, 217L, 1402L, 361L, 261L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2008.... = c(14896L, 
879L, 258L, 1566L, 480L, 314L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2009.... = c(17091L, 
1021L, 279L, 1710L, 579L, 366L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2010.... = c(20582L, 
1227L, 327L, 1962L, 833L, 420L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2011.... = c(23449L, 
1322L, 371L, 2065L, 1081L, 478L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2012.... = c(25944L, 
1312L, 390L, 2174L, 1356L, 518L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2013.... = c(26598L, 
1189L, 415L, 2129L, 1422L, 528L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2014.... = c(24829L, 
1046L, 401L, 1975L, 1370L, 508L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2015.... = c(22277L, 
849L, 363L, 1825L, 1202L, 478L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2016.... = c(22435L, 
813L, 470L, 1980L, 1148L, 497L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2017.... = c(20257L, 
741L, 419L, 1904L, 948L, 477L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2018.... = c(19207L, 
713L, 395L, 1948L, 877L, 491L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2006..ha. = c(228038L, 
19332L, 4846L, 19957L, 12094L, 3378L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2007..ha. = c(287529L, 
21988L, 5884L, 23934L, 18201L, 3561L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2008..ha. = c(314848L, 
28467L, 5943L, 26892L, 18207L, 4829L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2009..ha. = c(367062L, 
26427L, 6826L, 30113L, 22929L, 5270L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2010..ha. = c(519069L, 
39703L, 7688L, 34855L, 35797L, 7671L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2011..ha. = c(605520L, 
45547L, 8376L, 34837L, 44259L, 8746L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2012..ha. = c(661688L, 
44304L, 8813L, 37466L, 52581L, 9908L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2013..ha. = c(669970L, 
37455L, 11152L, 40819L, 54692L, 10342L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2014..ha. = c(657902L, 
37005L, 11573L, 38467L, 53300L, 11229L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2015..ha. = c(580730L, 
31261L, 10645L, 34052L, 46343L, 10158L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2016..ha. = c(536579L, 
29200L, 9263L, 31343L, 43235L, 9986L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2017..ha. = c(494978L, 
27542L, 8331L, 29001L, 37923L, 9260L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2018..ha. = c(484677L, 
27357L, 7655L, 28428L, 37174L, 8905L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My attempt:

```
rowSums(dane_csv[, 3:length(dane_csv$Nazwa=='POLSKA')])
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output from e.g. `dput(head(dane_csv))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
rowSums(dane_csv[sapply(dane_csv, is.numeric)])
```

-output

```
  1       2       3       4       5       6 
6667212  627833  511473 1033876 1288648 1108797
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dane_csv %>%
    transmute(out = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the most readable code for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can select only the numeric columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
  rowSums() %>%
  first()
```

Result:

```
      1 
6667212
```

Comment: perfect ! That is what I need. Is there any way to get only first value without other ones?

Comment: Yes, you can use dplyr's `first()` function! @focus87krk

Answer (score 0):

in base R use `Filter` function, to select the numeric columns then do a `rowSums` on them

```
rowSums(Filter(is.numeric, df))

      1       2       3       4       5       6 
6667212  627833  511473 1033876 1288648 1108797
```